# Get data from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I need to get data from multiple tables and put it into a subform.

The SubForm columns are 'product name' and 'quantity' and they need to list out the products relating to the order ID.

The tables in question are:

`PRODUCTS(productID,productName)`

`ORDER(orderID,prodID,quantity)`

Where the `prodID` in ORDER refers to the PRODUCTS table.

As you can see, the problem is that the name of the product is in a different table to the order. So, the data I need to get is:

`Products(productName)`

`Order(quantity)`

In relation to the `orderID`.

How can I use a SQL query to get this data? I am aware of joins and so on, but I just can't see how to apply it.

Thank you. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Design seems a bit odd to me  I would expect another table: orderediTems, so that way you are not repeating order information (date of order order by ship to etc) for each productID on the order.  Or does order have an "Order_header" or something?

Comment: @xQbert I do have a ORDRERITEMS table and an ORDERS table, yes. Sorry, I should have made that clearer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple SQL Select from 2 Tables (What is a Join?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040587/simple-sql-select-from-2-tables-what-is-a-join)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple inner join between  the two tables to return the rows you want:

```
SELECT P.PRODUCTNAME, O.QUANTITY
FROM PRODUCTS P INNER JOIN ORDER O ON P.PRODUCTID = O.PRODID
WHERE O.ORDERID = <order id>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
  PRODUCTS.productName AS productName,
  `ORDER`.quantity AS quantity
FROM
  `ORDER`
  INNER JOIN PRODUCTS on `ORDER`.prodID=PRODUCTS.productID
WHERE
 ..
```

You migh also want to rename the table ORDER - using reserved words as table names is not the best of styles.

Comment: +1 for noting that the ORDER table will need to be quoted, although only MySQL (as far as I know) uses backquotes.

Comment: Truly sorry, having SQL and MySQL being synonymous for too long I suspect.

Comment: I notice from the OP's profile that his other tags include Apache, PHP and Python - chances are he is using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Select p.productname, q.quantity from product_table p, quantity_table q where p.productId = q.productId;