# Can one column come another sql query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple SQL Select from 2 Tables (What is a Join?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040587/simple-sql-select-from-2-tables-what-is-a-join)

Can I bound another sql data source to only one column in gridview.

Shortly, there is a gridview which includes 3 columns.

I want to add one more column and show a different value while using another sql sentence.

Is it possible?

In order to explain easily, I write an example..

```
Name     |  Gender   |  Year
-------------------------------
AAA      |     M     |  1990 
-------------------------------
BBB      |     F     |  1991
```

These values come from one sql sentence.

```
Name     |  Tasks  | Gender   |  Year
--------------------------------------
AAA      |    20   |   M      |  1990 
--------------------------------------
BBB      |    2    |   F     |  1991
```

"Tasks" column will come from another sql sentence.

I want to count tasks which one employee have. So I use **count(*)**, but when I use it, I could not get another columns...

This subject is different from join.

Comment: what does exactly means 'sentence' in this context ?

Comment: Is it a query you could run at the same time as the first one? We could show you how to combine your two queries if you share them with us.

Comment: `JOIN` the two tables into one SQL sentence then use one datasource for this gridview.

Comment: You need to read and use a sql join most likely.

Comment: query, I made an english mistake, sry :)

Comment: Did you have a look into join statements? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Name,COUNT(*) as Tasks, a.Gender, a.Year 
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.Name = b.Name 
group by a.Name, a.Gender, a.Year
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a join statement like so:

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Gender, a.Year, b.New
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.Name = b.Name
```

(I may have messed up MySQL syntax, though, I'm coming from a different database world...)